# Add a button to refresh a element in a list

Tags: swift, list, swiftui

I have a list of questions and when the app is launched one randomly pops up. Now I want when a button is clicked it shows another random question in the list. Any ideas?

**This is my view**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ViewJouer2: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var data : DefisList
    var body: some View {
        List {
            if let randomDefi = data.defis.randomElement() {
                DefiRow(Defi: randomDefi)
            }
        }
    }
}
struct ViewJouer2_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ViewJouer2()
            .environmentObject(DefisList())
    }
}
```

**This is my Data**

```
import SwiftUI

class DefisList : ObservableObject {
    @Published var defis = [
        Defi(question: "How old are you?"),
        Defi(question: "How are you"),
        Defi(question: "What is your name?"),
    ]
}
struct Defi : Identifiable {
    var question : String
    
    var id = UUID()
}
```

Comment: Make `randomDefi` a `Published` variable of your `ObservedObject`.  Add a method to choose a random one and call that from your button.

Comment: Can you show me an example please? I don't get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `randomDefi` a `@Published` variable of your `ObservedObject`. Add a method called `randomize()` to choose a random one and call that from your button.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ViewJouer2: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var data : DefisList
    var body: some View {
        List {
            DefiRow(defi: data.randomDefi)
        }
        Button("random") {
            data.randomize()
        }
    }
}

class DefisList : ObservableObject {
    @Published var randomDefi = Defi(question: "")
    
    private var defis = [
        Defi(question: "How old are you?"),
        Defi(question: "How are you?"),
        Defi(question: "What is your name?"),
    ]
    
    init() {
        randomize()
    }
    
    func randomize() {
        randomDefi = defis.randomElement()!
    }
}

struct Defi : Identifiable {
    var question : String
    
    var id = UUID()
}

struct DefiRow: View {
    let defi: Defi
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(defi.question)
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to shuffle your list of questions and then choose questions from it until they are all gone.  This would avoid the problem of choosing the same question twice in a row.